# How does Rust handle shadowed variables?

Tags: rust

I have strong C/C++ background and am learning Rust these days. Got puzzled by how Rust handles shadowing variables. Particularly, I was expecting that the following code segment shall run without problem because `guess` is shadowed from a String to an integer before the next time it is called as a String in `read_line`.

Reading the API document, I understand `read_line` would append the next input to `guess`. But after the shadowing, should `guess` be considered as an integer and such appending be invalid? Please help.

```rust
fn main() {
    let secret_number = 10;
    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {
        //guess.clear(); // uncomment this line will make it work. 
        println!("Please input your guess:");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read guess.");
        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: As in C/C++, variable resolution and expression typing happens at compile-time, *before* any code execution occurs. (ie,

Comment: @user2864740 can you elaborate? In the example code, it feels that shadowing actually creates two variables underneath. Otherwise, it is hard for me to understand after the first execution of the `match` statement, `read_line` can be called and the `guess` string still holds the previous content.

Comment: That comment was to point out that one of the hypothesis presented ("..is shadowed from a String to an integer before the next time it is called as a..") is not correct as the 'next time' is a run-time execution artifact occurring *after* compilation. Or maybe I was reading that sentence wrong *shrug*.

Answer (score 5):

Shadowing is a purely syntactic phenomenon. It has no effect in the generated code, that is the generated code would be identical if you chose a different name for each variable. It is just that the shadowed variable cannot be referenced by name.

In particular, in your code:

```
    let mut guess = String::new(); //1
    ...    
    loop {
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)... //2
        let guess: u32 =  match guess.trim()... ; //3
        match guess.cmp(...) // 4
    }
    //5
```

The usages in line 2 and 3 refer to the declared variable in line 1, while the usage in line 4 refers to the declaration in line 3. There is no change in the type of the variable, nor there is any change in lifetimes. Simply they are two different variables that happen to have the same name, so that it will be impossible for your program to access the variable in line 1 from line 4.

In fact, after the loop finises, in line 5, the name `guess` will again refer to the variable in line 1, because the other one went out of scope.

Comment: Assuming the execution stayed in the `loop` after line `4`, which variable does `guess` refer to when the code executes line `2` again? It seems it falls back to referring the variable defined in line `1`. why? Also, because of the behavior of `read_line`, `guess.clear()` can only be called in the beginning of the loop since after line `3`, `guess` cannot be referred as a string any more. Does this make the whole code less elegant?

Comment: As I said, this is a syntactic matter: line 2 always refers to the variable in line 1, it just cannot change.

Comment: I think the better explanation goes like the following: during compile time, `guess` variable in line 2 is bound to definition in line 1, since at that time, only line 1's definition is in scope. Then every reference of `guess` in the loop after line 3 will be bound to the definition of `guess` in line 3. In this specific case, using shadow variable made things uglier (at least to me) since you now have to call `guess.clear()` at the beginning of the loop (i.e. before `read_line`) which makes the code look bad a confusing.

Comment: The merit of the story *don't use shadowing if the shadowed variable needs further processing down the road*.