# Rust book Listing 10-15:when i use 'let largest = item', the 'largest' can't be changed

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust by the rust book.But when I try the [Listing 10-15](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#fixing-the-largest-function-with-trait-bounds), I found I can't change the value of 'largest' by using 'let'. The introduction of the topic is

> Another way we could implement largest is for the function to return a reference to a T value in the slice. If we change the return type to &T instead of T, thereby changing the body of the function to return a reference, we wouldn’t need the Clone or Copy trait bounds and we could avoid heap allocations. Try implementing these alternate solutions on your own!

My code is:

```
fn largest<T>(list: &[T]) -> &T
    where T: PartialOrd + Copy
{
    let largest = &list[0];

    for item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            let largest = item;
        }
    }
    return largest
}


fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34.0, 50.2, 25.32, 100.32, 65.32, 100.33];
    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);

    let char_list = vec!['y', 'm', 'a', 'q'];
    let result = largest(&char_list);
    println!("The largest char is {}", result);
}
```

I get 1 warning:

```
warning: unused variable: `largest`
 --> src/main.rs:8:17
  |
8 |             let largest = item;
  |                 ^^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_largest`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

And the result is not right:

```
The largest number is 34
The largest char is y
```

Comment: Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235334/in-rust-whats-the-difference-between-shadowing-and-mutability https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844021/how-does-rust-handle-shadowed-variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422543/understanding-scope-and-shadowing-matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `let largest` creates a new block-scoped variable also named `largest` but unrelated to the outer largest. It is destroyed at the end of the loop cycle.

To fix your code remove the second `let` so that you have only one variable named `largest` and make the outer `largest` mutable so you can assign to it.

In fact, the only way this code works if you use the exact code form the book.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining again the variable `largest` inside another scope, so in fact you are shadowing it.
When the code exits the curly brackets `{}` than the internal `largest` disappears.
As the compiler said, the inner `largest` is in fact not used and the warning is correct.

[Scope and Shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/scope.html)